# Using minHeight with flex creates unexpected padding

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox, expo

#### code:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, borderColor: 'orange', borderWidth: 5 }}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, minHeight: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue', borderColor: 'blue', borderWidth: 5 }} />
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'pink', borderColor: 'red', borderWidth: 5 }} />
</View>
```

#### Screenshot:

Note the white space at the bottom. The two children View does not fill the parent view.
This only happens when `minHeight: 50` is added.
The height of the white space seems to be the same as the value of `minHeight`.

[image: asset]

#### Env:

- "expo": "^17.0.0",
- "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
- "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-17.0.0.tar.gz",

Real Device, both iPhone & Android.

Comment: What happens if you add `minHeight: 0` to the second element?

Comment: Also, to achieve a similar effect as `minHeight: 50` with standard flexbox, would be to set `flex: 1 0 50px;` to first child and `flex: 1 1 50px;` to the second

Comment: @LGSon adding `minHeight` to the second element has no effect.

Comment: What does each of the values in `flex: 1 1 50px;` mean?

Comment: `1` grow and take available space, `1` allow to shrink when no space available, `50px` be 50px high, which means it will be minimum 50px high if there is space. The first item, which has a `0` for second value (flex-shrink), mean be minimum 50px and don't shrink even if no place is available, which is similar to what `minHeight` does

Comment: According to RN's doc, flex has a different API then css:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#flex

Also I found that `minHeight` seems only work when `flex: -1`

Comment: If you can't combine `minHeight` with `flex: 1`, add a wrapper inside the first element and set it to `minHeight`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flexGrow instead of flex. Working example is given bellow.

```
<View style={{ flexGrow: 1, borderColor: 'orange', borderWidth: 5 }}>
   <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, minHeight: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue', borderColor: 'blue', borderWidth: 5 }} />
   <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, backgroundColor: 'pink', borderColor: 'red', borderWidth: 5 }} />
</View>
```

Here is the screenshot.

[image: flexGrow with minHeight]